# Pull out sections from XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

Please note that I have some Python experience but not a lot of deep experience so please bear with me.

I have a very large XML file, ~100 megs, that has many, many sections and subsections.  I need to pull out each subsection of a certain type (and there are a lot with this type) and write each to a different file.  The writing I can handle, but I'm staring at ElementTree documentation trying to make sense of how to traverse the tree, find an element declared this way, yank out just the data between those tags and process it, then continue down the file.

The structure is similar to this (slightly obfuscated).  What I want to do is pull out each section labeled "data" individually.

```
<filename>
    <config>
        <collections>   
        <datas>
            <data>
            ...
            </data>
            <data>
            ...
            </data>
            <data>
            ...
            </data>
        </datas>
        </collections>
     </config>
</filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can read in each `data` element using `iterparse` and then write it out, the following simply prints the element using the `print` function but you could of course instead write it to a file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
for event, elem in ET.iterparse("input.xml"):
  if elem.tag == 'data':
    print(ET.tostring(elem, 'UTF-8', 'xml'))
    elem.clear()
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider an [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) solution with Python's third-party module, [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/). Specifically, you `xpath()` for the length of `<data>` nodes and then iteratively build a dynamic XSLT script parsing only the needed element by node index `[#]` for outputted individual XML files:

```
import lxml.etree as et

dom = et.parse('Input.xml')
datalen = len(dom.xpath("//data"))

for i in range(1, datalen+1):

    xsltstr = '''<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="datas">    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data[{0}]" />    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data[{0}]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>        
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:transform>'''.format(i)

    xslt = et.fromstring(xsltstr)
    transform = et.XSLT(xslt)
    newdom = transform(dom)

    tree_out = et.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True, 
                           xml_declaration=True)    

    xmlfile = open('Data{}.xml', 'wb')
    xmlfile.write(tree_out)
    xmlfile.close()
```